# How to compute the following integral: $\int_{0}^{x}\{t\}^n dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $\{t\}=t-\lfloor{t}\rfloor$, where $\lfloor{t}\rfloor$ denotes the floor function of $t$.   I would like to show the following integral identity:

$$\int_{0}^{x}\{t\}^n dt\frac{}{}=\frac{x-\{x\}+\{x\}^{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{\lfloor{x}\rfloor+\{x\}^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

I first try letting $w=\{t\}=t-\lfloor{t}\rfloor$. Plugging in $x$ into $\{t\}$ we have $w=\{x\}=x-\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ and $w=0$, then $w+\lfloor{x}\rfloor=\{x\}+\lfloor{x}\rfloor=x,$ and $dw=dt$

$$\int_{0}^{x}\{t\}^n dt=\int_{0}^{x-\lfloor{x}\rfloor}w^{n} dw=\frac{w^{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{(x-\lfloor{x}\rfloor)^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

I must be using the wrong substitution or there is something wrong to my algebra   If someone can give the proper correction, I would much appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: The integral of floor turns into a discrete sum. Do you see why? Floor is a step function...

Comment: @Fshrike if we have the definite integral of a floor function, I apply the Abel summation formula to it to turn it into a discrete sum. But we have something like ${x}^{n+1}$ at the end.  I am not sure if that formula applies to fractional part of x function along with the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to apply the definition of the floor function we have to split the interval of integration $[0,x]$ at each the integer point. Since for $t\in [n,n+1)$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $\lfloor t \rfloor=n$, then
$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{x}\{t\}^n dt&=\int_{0}^{x}(t-\lfloor t \rfloor)^n dt=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}(t-k)^n dt+\int_{\lfloor x \rfloor}^{x}(t-\lfloor x \rfloor)^n dt\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor-1}\int_{0}^{1}s^n ds+\int_{0}^{x-\lfloor x \rfloor}s^n ds=\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{n+1}+\frac{(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)^{n+1}}{n+1}\\&=\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor+\{x\}^{n+1}}{n+1}.
\end{align}$$

P.S. The function $t\to \{t\}^n $ is a periodic function of period $1$. Its integral over one period is $$\int_{0}^{1}\{t\}^n dt=\int_{0}^{1}t^n dt=\frac{1}{n+1}.$$
Therefore the right-hand side of the above result can be read as $\lfloor x \rfloor$ times the integral of a period plus a fraction of it.

Comment: I have three questions (1) when you say "for $t \in [n,n+1)$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $\lfloor t \rfloor=n$"  Is that an equivalent way of defining the floor function.  Meaning $t \in [n,n+1)$ implies that  $t\neq 0$ iff $t=[t]=n$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $t=0$ iff $t\in (n,n+1)$.  (2) do I let $s=(t-\lfloor x \rfloor).$ (3) how do you show that "integral over one period is $\int_{0}^{1}s^n ds=\frac{1}{n+1}$"?

Comment: @SethMai (1) Yes, (2) Yes, (3) I added a few more details

Comment: When I am dealing with the integral $\int_{k}^{k+1}(t-k)^n dt$, for  say $k=1$ and $n=2$, we have $\int_{1}^{2}(t-k)^2 dt=\int_{1}^{2}s^2 ds=\frac{s^3}{3}=\frac{(t-k)^3}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$  I don't need further justification for the step $\int_{1}^{2}(t-k)^2 dt=\int_{1}^{2}s^2 ds=\frac{s^3}{3}$ other than letting $s=(t-k)$ and $ds=dt$.

Comment: $\int_{1}^{2}(t-1)^2 dt\not= \int_{1}^{2}s^2 ds$. When you set $s=t-1$ the interval of integration $[1,2]$ changes into $[0,1]$. Hence $\int_{1}^{2}(t-1)^2 dt=\int_{0}^{1}s^2 ds$

Comment: ops, sorry I forgot about letting $k=1$ for $s=t-k$.  Also, thank you so very much for your detailed explanations.  I have seen the phrasing in question (1) in my comment.   I asked multiple times about that on this site.  I think you are the first one who confirmed whether I am understanding that phrasing correctly.